# How to fix the problem of " Unhandled exception from message handler method " for chatbox using springboot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-websocket

I am trying to build chat box using springboot+thymeleaf in java.I am having an error for sending a call from UI to controller. Whenever I enter the username and click on send it gives an error saying `Unhandled exception from message handler method`. 
I have downloaded the chatbox code from online and I have integerated the code with my existing project.If I run the project independently it works perfectly fine but if I integrate with my project it gives me the error.

My .js has the below method which call chat.addUser.

**Main.js**

```
function onConnected() {

        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/publicChatRoom', onMessageReceived); // Subscribe to the Public Topic

        // Tell your username to the server
        stompClient.send("/app/chat.addUser",
            {},
            JSON.stringify({sender: username, type: 'JOIN'})
        )

        connectingElement.classList.add('hidden');
    }
```

My WebSocketChatController look like this

**WebSocketController.java**

```
    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/publicChatRoom")
    public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        // Add username in web socket session
        System.out.println("In addUser");
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username",chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;
    }
```

In this controller I am unable to call (`"/chat.addUser"`).My output is like this when I enter the username.

Output:

```
    2019-05-30 17:11:50,228  [34mINFO [0;39m [-8081-exec-6] [36mcom.bmc.app.config.WebLogAspect         [0;39m : RESPONSE : chat 
    2019-05-30 17:11:50,228  [34mINFO [0;39m [-8081-exec-6] [36mcom.bmc.app.config.WebLogAspect         [0;39m : SPEND TIME : 1 
    2019-05-30 17:11:50,228  [34mINFO [0;39m [-8081-exec-6] [36mcom.bmc.app.config.WebLogAspect    [0;39m :
    2019-05-30 17:12:11,853  [34mINFO [0;39m [-8081-exec-2] [36mc.b.a.listener.HttpHandshakeInterceptor [0;39m : Call beforeHandshake 
    2019-05-30 17:12:11,855  [34mINFO [0;39m [-8081-exec-2] [36mc.b.a.listener.HttpHandshakeInterceptor [0;39m : Call afterHandshake 
    2019-05-30 17:12:11,863  [34mINFO [0;39m [undChannel-7] [36mc.b.a.config.WebSocketChatEventListener [0;39m : Received a new web socket connection 
    2019-05-30 17:12:14,899  [1;31mERROR[0;39m [ndChannel-23] [36m.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler[0;39m : Unhandled exception from message handler method 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.bmc.app.config.WebLogAspect.doBefore(WebLogAspect.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor238.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Apparently their is something `null` in `WebLogAspect.doBefore(WebLogAspect.java:33)`. Can you provide the source for that?